# How to clear RAM or Dropcache using Ansible in Linux Systems

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook for which i need to clear the Ram. I have been doing this by using command 
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches.

I can use shell module to do this but is there any better approach to do this in Ansible??

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unsure about solution. But if you want something different you can try to use copy module.

```
- name: clean RAM
  copy:
    content: 3 
    dest: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
    unsafe_writes: yes
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not work & gave error as fatal: [aw1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "77de68daecd823babbb58edb1c8e14d7106e83bb", "msg": "Destination /proc/sys/vm not writable"}

Comment: Yep. I have added *unsafe_writes: yes*. I tested. Looks like work